# in-line ASM addressing in OSX

Tags: macos, assembly, 32bit-64bit, mining

I am getting this issue compiling on osx

*fatal error: error in backend: 32-bit absolute addressing is not supported in 64-bit mode*

by this line of code in inline-ASM:

```
movq    grsoT0(,%%rdi,8), %%mm1
```

OSX does not allow me to define absolute addressing, I need to convert this to relocatable addressing. Could you help me? I don't know how.... I don't really understand this line.
(trying to port a software on OSX)

Comment: "\n movq grsoT0(%%rip,%%rdi,8), %%mm1" is this going to work? to be position independent?

Comment: No, rip-relative addresses can only have an immediate displacement, no other parts (such as index and scale)

Comment: thanks, it actually compiled but I don't know what I am doing so I don't know if this is going to break my code. As you said, I probably should get rid of index and scale.. :O

Comment: If you made a change you don't understand to code you don't understand it almost certainly will break that code.

Comment: Side note: all x86-64 chips have SSE2, so using MMX is a wasted effort.